Как получить timezone по координатам в php
Как получить tz в php используя сервисы YANDEX или что-то другое, но бесплатное

Аналогичный вопрос на en-сайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Ответ и вопрос одновременно? Оригинально ...

@DanielProtopopov, ничего сверхестественного т.к. предусмотрена даже галочка при написании вопроса "Ответить на свой вопрос" и сразу пишется ответ. Я потратил время и поделился с сообществом, ибо может кому-нибудь помочь

ага. осталось только понять, при чем тут php и laravel. особенно учитывая, что для РНР ответ на сервисе уже есть

Встала задача начать получать tz по коордам и чтобы это было одно из 2х
Получать TZ апишками Yandex, но у них нет http апи под эту задачу(геокодер не говорит tz)
или
Получать tz из чего-то внешнего и бесплатного
Намучавшись пришёл к решению в pyhton т.к. там есть корректно работающий timezonefinder и считаю, что нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы в проект на php поместить простенький скрипт на py в корень проекта
Мини инструкция как прийти к этому:

Установка python:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip

2.Ставим либу:
pip3 install timezonefinder


Пишем скрипт определяющий tz (я назвал его get_timezone.py):

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
import json

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: get_timezone.py <latitude> <longitude>")
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        latitude = float(sys.argv[1])
        longitude = float(sys.argv[2])
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Latitude and longitude must be numbers.")
        sys.exit(1)

    tf = TimezoneFinder()
    timezone_str = tf.timezone_at(lat=latitude, lng=longitude)

    result = {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "timezone": timezone_str
    }

    print(json.dumps(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Делаем скрипт исполняемым:

chmod +x get_timezone.py


Тестим скрипт:

./get_timezone.py 37.7749 -122.4194

*Вывод
6. Вызов скрипта из php (путь к скрипту пропишите свой)
shell_exec(__DIR__.'/get_timezone.py 37.7749 -122.4194');


Я очень надеюсь, что помог кому-то из вас и не закидаете дизами, это решило мою проблему и довольно легко
